# Tabularx inside tabularx in a scrartcl class based document

Tags: koma-script, tabularx, two-column

I am using a template which uses a `scrartcl` based class. In this class I have two commands (`\part` and `\personal`) both using `tabularx`. I am trying to put as the second argument of `\part`, the box generated with the command `\personal`.

Putting the command as an argument is giving an error and also, when I added `tabularx` to the command `\part`, the text is no longer centered even though I specified `\begin{center}`.

Here is the class with all the commands:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{tccv}
              [2012/11/09 v1.0
 Two Column Curriculum Vitae]

\LoadClass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\RequirePackage[hmargin=1.25cm,vmargin=1.25cm,twocolumn,columnsep=1.25cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{bookman,etoolbox,hyperref,needspace,tabularx,xcolor,fontawesome}

% Capitalize words of at least a minimum length (default to 3 chars).
% The text is capitalized before being expanded.
%
% This macro uses Lua to do the job but fails gracefully (that is,
% return the text as is) if \directlua is not available.
%
% |[
% \ucwords[optional: miminum length]{text}
% ]|
\newcommand\ucwords[2][3]{%
    % Fails gracefully if not in LuaLaTeX
    \providecommand\directlua[1]{#2}%
    \directlua{%
    local minlen=tonumber("#1")
    local src="\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}"
    local dst={}
    for w in src:gmatch('[^\string\%s]+') do
        if w:len() >= minlen then w = w:sub(1,1):upper()..w:sub(2) end
        table.insert(dst, w)
    end
    tex.print(dst)}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\color[HTML]{303030} % Default foreground color
\definecolor{link}{HTML}{506060} % Hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=link,linkcolor=link}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{0058B6}}
\setkomafont{section}{\scshape\Large\mdseries}

% In tccv \part must contain the subject of the curriculum vitae.
% The command will start a new page and output in onecolumn the
% subject (first and last name) with the hardcoded text
% "Curriculum vitae" under it.
\renewcommand\part[2]{%
    \twocolumn[%
    \begin{center}
    \vskip-\lastskip%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ r | l }
    {\usekomafont{part} #1} & {#2} %\medskip\\
    %{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont\Huge Curriculum vitae}
    \end{tabularx}
    \bigskip
    \end{center}]}

% Overrides the \section command to capitalize every
% word for cosmetic purposes and draws a rule under it.
\makeatletter
\let\old@section\section
\renewcommand\section[2][]{%
    \old@section[#1]{\ucwords{#2}}%
    \newdimen\raising%
    \raising=\dimexpr-0.7\baselineskip\relax%
    \vskip\raising\hrule height 0.4pt\vskip-\raising}
\makeatother

% Allow conditionals based on the job name. This can usually be set
% from a command-line argument: check fausto.en.tex for an example.
%
% |[
% \ifjob{jobname}{content if matches}{content if does not match}
% ]|
\newcommand\ifjob[3]{%
    \edef\JOBNAME{\jobname}%
    \edef\PIVOT{\detokenize{#1}}%
    \ifdefstrequal{\JOBNAME}{\PIVOT}{#2}{#3}%
}

% Renders a personal data box:
%
% |[
% \personal[optional: web site without scheme (no http:// prefix)]
%          {address}{phone number}{email}
% ]|
\newcommand\personal[4][]{%
    \needspace{0.5\textheight}%
    \newdimen\boxwidth%
    \boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
    \colorbox[HTML]{C7E2F2}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c|X}
    \faMapMarker  & {#2}\smallskip\\
    \faPhone     & {#3}\smallskip\\
    \faEnvelope      & \href{mailto:#4}{#4}
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \faLinkedin & \href{http://www.#1}{#1}}
    \end{tabularx}}}

% Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
% are allowed:
%
% |[
% \item{fact}{description}
% ]|
\newenvironment{factlist}{%
    \newdimen\unbaseline
    \unbaseline=\dimexpr-\baselinestretch\baselineskip\relax
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
    \textsc{##1} & {\raggedright ##2\medskip\\}\\[\unbaseline]}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{rX}}
    {\endtabularx}

%% End of file `tccv.cls'.
```

And this is the latex document:

```
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}

\begin{document}

\part{Name}{\personal
    {Address }
    {+33 654 32 10 98}
    {someone@gmail.com}}

\section{Languages}

\begin{factlist}
\item{Spanish}{Native speaker}
\item{English}{Level C2 }
\item{French}{Level C1 }
\end{factlist}

\section{Software skills}

Python $\bullet$ Java $\bullet$ JavaScript $\bullet$ Matlab $\bullet$ Android Studio $\bullet$ Microsoft Office $\bullet$ C $\bullet$ \LaTeX $\bullet$ Solid Edge $\bullet$ Altium $\bullet$ Arduino

\end{document}
```

So basically I would like to have the blue box replacing *Here is where the box should go*, as shown in image. Thanks in advance for your suggestions!
[image]

EDIT: I have cleaned the code. When speaking of having the command `\part` centered, I mean that the *Name* is centered in the page (normally the layout is two-column so I would like only the Name|Box to be in the center of the page.

EDIT 2: I have change the latex document with what I wanted to achieve and gave me an error.

Comment: Can you remove the code which is not relevant to your question? What is the text of the error you get? Note that a `tabularx` requires at least one `X`-type column, that `hyperref` should be loaded late and that you need to box the stuff you put in the argument of `\twocolumn`, probably.

Comment: Don't use `\makeatletter` or `\makeatother` in a class or package file. And don't use `\\ ` to break lines outside tabulars etc.

Comment: I have removed unnecessary code, why shouldn't I use \makeatletter and \makeatother in a class? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, @ is already a letter. When you say `\makeatother` you are setting the catcodes to something which is not standard for class and package files. That is, LaTeX expects (and other things you load expect) that @ is other here. So `\makeatletter` is pointless and `\makeatother` is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear what you want centred.

Here are two much minimised versions.

```
\begin{filecontents}{tccv.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{tccv} [2012/11/09 v1.0 Two Column Curriculum Vitae]

\LoadClass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage[hmargin=1.25cm,vmargin=1.25cm,twocolumn,columnsep=1.25cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{array,tabularx}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\renewcommand\part[2]{%
  \twocolumn[%
  \begin{center}
    \vskip-\lastskip%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ r | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X }
      {\usekomafont{part} #1} & {#2}
    \end{tabularx}
    \bigskip
  \end{center}]}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{tccv}

\begin{document}

\part{Name}{Here is where the box should go}

\end{document}
```

[image: version 1]

Note that all the `center` environment does here is add vertical space, since the tabular is `\linewidth` wide, so takes the whole line.

If you don't want that, you might want

[image: version 2]

```
\renewcommand\part[2]{%
  \twocolumn[%
    \vskip-\lastskip%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X | X }
      {\usekomafont{part} \hfill #1} & {#2}
    \end{tabularx}
    \bigskip]}
```

More likely, you want neither version, but something more like the following.

[image: square-one]

```
\renewcommand\part[2]{%
  \twocolumn[%
    \vskip-\lastskip
      {\usekomafont{part}\hfill #1 \textbar\ }#2\hfill\bigskip\par]}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions, when I get back home I will try your solutions. Have you managed to replace the second argument with the box or it gives you an error?

Comment: @JuanCastillo No. I didn't understand your question well enough to figure out which box you meant and I didn't have an error message to provide a clue, either, so I just focussed on the centring bit. I didn't understand that either, but I could generate a number of possible interpretations.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear,  I will update the post with the errors I get when I get back home. As for the centering part, the last solution is the one I was looking for. I have changed the code to show the error I am getting. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I have tried your second suggestion and it even fixes the other issue! Thanks!

Comment: @JuanCastillo Stroke of luck, I guess, since I certainly didn't design it to do what I didn't understand at the time :-).